# LDAP support in PHP 7 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap, php-7

Has anyone succeeded in getting LDAP support functions to work in PHP 7, without needing to build PHP 7 and OpenLDAP from scratch?

In PHP 5 it seemed you just needed `apt-get install php5-ldap`.